# OpenCV Android - Cannot Resolve Corresponding JNI Function

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to setup Android Studio with Opencv by following this tutorial outlined here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTw_GIQNbD8

I can get the result obtained by the person giving the tutorial but upon trying to actually use some of Opencv's functions I run into some trouble.

I am able to load the Opencv library but upon trying use some of the native functions such as "Imgcodecs.imread" I get the error: ".lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(java.lang.String)"

I believe I have tracked down the issue to the following:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

It seems that Android Studio is unable to detect the native C++ code which I'm guessing should be picked up from jniLibs folder I now have in app/src/main?

I've tried updating Android Studio to the latest stable build and I have fixed my file paths for my android SDK and NDK as having white-space can apparently affect the running of native code. The issue still persists.

I have been trying to fix this for the last 4 hours, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: which Java file is showing the error in your screenshot?

Comment: @AlexCohn Imgcodecs.java in openCVLibrary300/src/main/java/org/opencv/imgcodecs

Comment: I would say - ignore this error, it is only Android Studio failing to understand the native library. But I don't have first-hand experience with Java wrappers for OpenCV.

Comment: @AlexCohn I can't unfortunately because when trying to read in an image using Imgcodecs.imread() the app crashes with the error message I posted in my original question.

Comment: Then, you probably don't get the OpenCV native libraries packed into your APK. Specify `model {
        android.sources {
            main.jniLibs.source {
                srcDirs += "OpenCV_libs"
            }
        }
    }` and put the missing libraries there.

Comment: @AlexCohn Could you specify which build.gradle file I should include that line in? I'm new to Android and Gradle, sorry.

Comment: The file in app module folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINAL EDIT: I've made a tutorial explaining how to install Opencv for Android along with SIFT/SURF algorithms - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLK9CjQ-pNI

It appears that I have solved my issue with using the following file structure and dependencies. I can't say for sure how I got it to work but I believe if you copy my structure here then yours should work too.

Ensure that there are no spaces present in your file path to your Android SDK or NDK. Android Studio warns that this may cause issue when loading native code.

Place the folders containing the '*.so' files into /YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT/libs (You'll probably have to manually create this libs folder).
All the other solutions online stating to put them into app/src/main/jniLibs did not work for me.

To include the openCVLibrary300, I imported it as a module using File->New->Import Module, the set the Source Directory to something like ..\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\java

Ensure build.gradle files in both the app and the imported library share the same min and max sdk version etc.

Sample code used to test - http://pastebin.com/2zzU5B9G

The sample code I've posted above ensures the libraries are loaded before using Opencv methods. It uses the Imgcodecs.imread() function that uses native code in C++ that was previously giving me the ".lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(java.lang.String)" error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just set this up this weekend following this tutorial:  https://blog.hig.no/gtl/2015/10/01/android-studio-opencv/  It worked, but I noticed my apk was huge, almost 40megs because it adds all the native binaries to the apk.  I was thinking of seeing if I could remove all those native lib binaries, and get it to use the Android Opencv manager installed on the phone, but I'm not entirely clear how it all works atm.

Comment: @medloh: have you found the solution with **split** to reduce the size of APK?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Opencv Manager now.  It dramatically reduced the size of my APK because no native code is included in my APK anymore.  The only downside is the user has to install opencv manager first, but they will be prompted to do so automatically if they haven't installed it by the time you run your app.  All you need to do is make a call to OpenCVLoader.initAsync(), and then it will magically find all the native opencv libs it needs from OpenCV Manager.

Comment: @ConorB i followed your tutorial and got **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:**

Answer (score 4):

I think I am the right person to give you a practical answer on this problem after solving the ndk issue with Android Studio before struggling for a week. It means that you have solved the issue but I can give more information on how to setup your own native files in case you need it.

The first thing you have to know is that currently Android Studio still has some internal flaws and the native function declarations in the Java source files might still trigger a "Cannot resolve..." message. It is ok actually, as long as all your sources codes are correct and you have done the compilation correctly, nothing will be wrong.

If you don't have your own native files (C++,C) in your project, just put the .a or .so native libraries in the src/main/jniLibs folders and you don't have to modify anything in the gradle file. The system will do everything for you automatically.

If you have own native files and have put them in the src/main/jni folder, then you have to create your own makefiles and put them in the jni folder as well. You also have to modify the gradle file in your app module.

Here is what I did for a face detection sample of opencv, and I got the original code from this wonderful post([Here](http://hujiaweibujidao.github.io/blog/2014/10/22/android-ndk-and-opencv-development-with-android-studio/)), which was actually modified from another one's method for simpler execution:

My project structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itABV.png)

My makefiles (make sure you have the original sdk of the library for reference in the makefile):

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include /home/ng/Desktop/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := detection_based_tracker

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk:

```
    APP_STL := gnustl_static
    APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
    APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi
    APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

My gradle.build file in the app module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.opencv.samples.facedetect"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []

    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
       // ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').getNdkFolder()
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary300')
}
```

You don't actually have to change other gradle files for compiling the native part of the project.
You could also compile the native sources codes by command line and put the .so files back to the jniLibs folder. This also works.
I hope this could help in your problem.