# Android Studio: Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, fft

I have read [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455235/opencv-android-cannot-resolve-corresponding-jni-function) and 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566558/android-cannot-find-corresponding-jni-function), but I still can't make things work.

The problem is the same, I'm trying to use FFTS in Android Studio 1.5.1, the so files are generated, but Android Studio can't find the native methods and `UnsatisflyLinkError` is thrown.

Edit:
I found the problem is my function does not be compiled into the so file.

**cpu_check.c**

```
#ifdef ANDROID
#include <jni.h>
#include <cpu-features.h>

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_nz_ac_waikato_ffts_FFTS_has_neon
(JNIEnv *env, jclass jc)
{
    if (android_getCpuFamily() == ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_ARM &&
        (android_getCpuFeatures() & ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_NEON) != 0)
    return JNI_TRUE;

    // use NEON-optimized routines

    else
    return JNI_FALSE;

    // use non-NEON fallback routines instead
}
#endif
```

When I look into compiled libcpucheck.so, it does not have `~has_neon` function. But it has size 16K with some functions like CPU checking. Here is my **Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := cpucheck
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cpu_check.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ffts
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := jni/include jni/src
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_DECL_MEMALIGN -std=c99 \
    -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ffts_jni.c \
    src/ffts.c \
    src/ffts_nd.c \
    src/ffts_real.c \
    src/ffts_real_nd.c \
    src/ffts_small.c \
    src/patterns.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog 

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
LOCAL_MODULE := ffts-vfp
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_VFP
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    src/codegen.c \
    src/vfp.s
endif

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ffts
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := jni/include jni/src
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_DECL_MEMALIGN -std=c99 \
    -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ffts_jni.c \
    src/ffts.c \
    src/ffts_nd.c \
    src/ffts_real.c \
    src/ffts_real_nd.c \
    src/ffts_small.c \
    src/patterns.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog 

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
LOCAL_MODULE := ffts-neon
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_NEON
LOCAL_ARM_NEON := true
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    src/codegen.c \
    src/neon.s
endif

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)
```

Comment: Do you call `static { System.loadLibrary("ffts"); }` in your Activity java source file? What is your exact error log? Is the `Java_nz_ac_waikato_ffts_FFTS_has_neon` implemented in `ftts.cpp`?

Comment: Yes. I fount that the problem was: The function is not compiled into so file. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Your files look correct. If the question is still relevant, please try to run `ndk-build V=1` and post the *verbose* build log for further analysis.